# Error - is not marked as serializable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, serialization

The error I'm getting is:

```
Type 'OrgPermission' in Assembly 'App_Code.ptjvczom, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.
```

here is my code:

I have a gridview, that uses the following DataSource:

```
 <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetOrgList" 
            TypeName="Org">
    <SelectParameters>
      <asp:SessionParameter Name="orgCodes" SessionField="UserOrgs" Type="Object" />
       <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Y" Name="active" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
 </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I set the session variable in my page load like so:

```
User cUser = new User(userid);
//make sure the user is an Admin
List<OrgPermission> orgs = new List<OrgPermission>();
foreach(OrgPermission org in cUser.orgs)
   {
     if (org.type=='admin')
     {
        orgs.Add(org);                       
     }
   }
Session["UserOrgs"] = orgs;
```

My user class looks like this:

```
public class OrgPermission
{
    public string Org { get; set; }   
    public List<string> type { get; set; }

    public OrgPermission()
    { }    
}
public class cUser
{    
    public string userid { get; set; }
    public List<OrgPermission> orgs { get; set; }

    public clsUser(string username)
    {
      //i set everything here
    }
}
```

I can't understand why it's breaking, can I use it without making it serializable?

I tried to debug, and the session variable sets just fine, it then goes into the GetOrgList and returned correct results, but the page does not load and I get the error above.

Here is a snippet of my GetOrgList function:

```
public DataTable GetOrgList(List<OrgPermission> orgCodes, string active)
    {

        string orgList = null;

        //code to set OrgList using the parameter is here.

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cCon.getConn());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetOrgList", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@orgList", orgList));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@active", active));

            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter();

            sqlDA.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sqlDA.Fill(ds);

            conn.Close();
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
```

Answer (score 189, accepted):

You need to add a `Serializable` attribute to the class which you want to serialize.

```
[Serializable]
public class OrgPermission
```

Comment: Just as important is *why* you must add that serializable tag: any object put into a session variable (other than base objects like ints and bools) must be marked as serializable. Note that some .NET classes are not by default - i.e. DataView.

Comment: I have stored my List type object type in `Viewstate` and it showed me the same error when I tried to use it as DataSource for a repeater control. Does it also apply for the `Viewstate` along with `Session State`?

Comment: Didn't work for me; I think this is being caused by something else for me.This error doesn't always appear. But when it does, there's nothing I can do.Can't rebuild or save. I'm left to re-start VS and loose work.

Comment: My web server was using IIS-7.5 and i didn't have the Serializable attribute, once I moved to IIS-10 i'm getting the non serialize error, can somebody tell me why it was not throwing the error on IIS-7.5 ? I'm storing a class into a session key.

Answer (score 18):

If you store an object in session state, that object must be serializable.

http://www.hpenterprisesecurity.com/vulncat/en/vulncat/dotnet/asp_dotnet_bad_practices_non_serializable_object_stored_in_session.html

---

edit:

In order for the session to be serialized correctly, all objects the application stores as session attributes must declare the [Serializable] attribute. Additionally, if the object requires custom serialization methods, it must also implement the ISerializable interface.

https://vulncat.hpefod.com/en/detail?id=desc.structural.dotnet.asp_dotnet_bad_practices_non_serializable_object_stored_in_session#C%23%2fVB.NET%2fASP.NET

Comment: Not for mode = InProc

Comment: The page that you requested could not be found.

Comment: Neither page you requested can be found

Comment: Links not found.  add the pertinent info to this page

Answer (score 5):

Leaving my specific solution of this for prosperity, as it's a tricky version of this problem:

`Type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator[T...] was not marked as serializable`

Due to a class with a field of type `IEnumerable<int>` eg:

```
[Serializable]
class MySessionData{
    public int ID;
    public IEnumerable<int> RelatedIDs; //This can be an issue
}
```

Originally the problem instance of `MySessionData` was set from a non-serializable list:

```
MySessionData instance = new MySessionData(){ 
    ID = 123,
    RelatedIDs = nonSerizableList.Select<int>(item => item.ID)
};
```

The cause here is the concrete class that the `Select<int>(...)` returns, **has type data that's not serializable**, and you need to copy the id's to a fresh `List<int>` to resolve it.

```
RelatedIDs = nonSerizableList.Select<int>(item => item.ID).ToList();
```

Comment: RelatedIDs is a member (field), not an attribute. But thanks for sharing the information.