# how to mark an object as Serializable

Tags: c#, wpf, serializable, documents, cloning

I have a system.document.table object and i want to mark that object as Serializable for deep cloning it. the exception is **Type 'System.Windows.Documents.Table' in Assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.**

```
 FlowTable original =  new FlowTable();
 original = objFlowTab.deepclone();
```

where objflowtab is having a table object

```
[Serializable]
public class FlowTable : Table
{ ....
  ....
  public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    // Deep clone
    public static T DeepClone<T>(this T a)
    { 

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {

            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream,a);
            stream.Position = 0;
            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

i am getting error in formatter.Serialize(stream,a);

Comment: Please show some code in addition to the error message.

Comment: this should have been found out quickly by searching yourself first. Looks like you have never searched for anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error - is not marked as serializable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707872/error-is-not-marked-as-serializable)

Comment: be sure that your object does not have any members which cannot be serialized (such as of some type which also does not have `Serializable` marked). In some cases you need to implement the interface `ISerializable` explicitly.

Comment: Bad idea. Serialize table to XAML. I doubt, that binary serialization will work here.

Answer (score 9):

Add a `[Serializable]` attribute to the class being serialized.

See details about C# serialization [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

For serializable objects you have to include `[Serializable]` with your class definition

```
[Serializable]
public class YourClass
{
  //Your definition here;
}
```