# I am getting an error in Visual Studio 2015 any time I try to save this file

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I'm using VS2015 and trying to edit a specific WinForms file in design view (from a solution that has been migrated from previous version of VS). Whenever I edit the file *at all* - move a control, change a property, anything - I get this error when I try to save it:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
--------------------------
Type 'System.Windows.Forms.UserControl' in Assembly 'System.Windows.Forms,
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not 
marked as serializable.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15707872/127888) similar post and gone to every class that inherits from `System.Windows.Forms.UserControl` in my solution and added the `[Serializable]` attribute to the class and I'm still getting the same error.

Any idea what the issue could be here, or steps to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error - is not marked as serializable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707872/error-is-not-marked-as-serializable)

Comment: @Reddy Thanks for finding that - but I tried it to no avail.