# Serialize GameObject in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, gameobject, audioclip

I have class like -

```
[serializable]
public class DemoClass{
    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject gameObject;
}
```

I want to store data using serializable. Unity doc says GameObject is serializeField. But it gives Exception -

```
SerializationException: Type UnityEngine.GameObject is not marked as Serializable.
```

Anyone have idea about it ?

Comment: Did you google the error at all? First hit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707872/error-is-not-marked-as-serializable

Comment: Yes! I google it.But GameObject is not allowing to be serialize.

Comment: You can't. That's the answer. You simply can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the tag `[Serializable]` before your class name:

```
[Serializable]
public class DemoClass{
    public GameObject gameObject;
    public AudioClip audio;
}
```

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Edit:** ff you still want to serialize `GameObject` their is some plugins out there that allow to Serialize Unity Objects. See: [Runtime Serialization for Unity](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/released-runtime-serialization-for-unity-extremely-easy-solution-to-save-your-gameplay-data.325812/)

Comment: I use this. But Gameobject is not allow to serialize it gives Exception.

Comment: @AnkitaKorape Why do you want to serialize a `GameObject` ?

Comment: I have many assetBundles. When first time i download it using www, i don't want to download/cache it again.Because it occupies so much of phone memory and app gets crashes.So I want to save data for further use.

Comment: @AnkitaKorape Ok have a look at my edit it should solve your issue

Comment: Can someone explain when a class has to be serializable? I looked in the documentation and it says to apply it when it is serializable? Oh, and make it laymen's terms please.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the `[serializable]` attribute to the classes that you wish to serialize.  If any of the classes within your class are not already serializable, you will need to add this attribute to those classes as well.

e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class DemoClass
{
   public GameObject gameObject;
   public AudioClip audio;
}
```

Comment: I use this. But Gameobject is not allow to serialize it gives Exception