# Error when upgrading .Net Framework from 3.5 to 4.6

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I tried to upgrade the .Net Framework from 3.5 to 4.6

After upgrading to 4.6 it showing the following error message

**Type 'System.Web.UI.RenderTraceListener+RenderTraceListenerList' in Assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated

I tried to put the following code in web.config but still it showing the same error message

```
<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
</startup>
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707872/error-is-not-marked-as-serializable

Comment: Hi Phu Minh Pham,


Thanks for the update, I tried to put Serializable as follows but no luck


[Serializable]
public partial class Login : PageBase