# Visual Studio Custom ToolBox Item Collection Value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, toolbox

i am currently working on my own TabControl, just to give me more options in customization.
To come along with this, i've made my own TabPage too.

Edit: Rewrote my question with pictures:

I want this Field:

[image]

After Clicking on "Collection" you gain a new Box to "Add" and "Remove" the Values

So here's what i've done:

[image]

If i now hit "Add" some pages appear, if i hit "remove" some pages disappear.
So far so good.

Clicking on "OK" does not show them up (but they are still there, after reopening the menu)

[image]

Now the random stuff happens:
If i press "Cancel" all the 'tabs' are generated.
If i open the menu again, all the "tabPages" are shown as there ClassType.

[image]

Here is the code of my TabControl Class

```
    //The List for my TabPages
    List<FancyTabPage> listPages = new List<FancyTabPage>();

    //My Wrapper to get the Menu for the Designer shown in the Picture
    public List<FancyTabPage> Pages
    {
        set { this.listPages = value; drawTabPages(); }
        get { return this.listPages;  }
    }

    //My function to generate the buttons
    private void drawTabPages()
    {
        this.Controls.Clear();

        resizeTabPages();

        int zaehlerMax = listPages.Count;
        
        for (int zaehler = 0; zaehler != zaehlerMax; zaehler++)
        {
            this.Controls.Add(listPages[zaehler].PageButton);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Base on the code provided, It's hard to reproduce the issue. Could you provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Besides, what function do you want to achieve by custom TabControl? What is the difference between it and the default built-in TabControl?

Comment: @KyleWang trying to make a project with just these elements throws an exception. "System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException; The Type "MyProject.MyTabPage" in Assembly "Project, Version, Culture, PublicKeyToken" is not defined as seriazable".
Maybe this happens in the background with my primary project too..

Comment: For this error, did you mark the class with `Serializable` attribute? [Related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707872/error-is-not-marked-as-serializable)

Comment: @KyleWang i've marked it now, rebuilt my project but changed nothing :(